# Cross-platform python venv

Tags: python, django, linux, windows, python-venv

I build a Django Site using venv on my windows laptop.
Uploaded the venv to Digital Ocean server running ubuntu(using putty).

Once you have made a venv on windows what is the best way to get a working env on linux?

Comment: Virtual environments don't work like that - you certainly shouldn't try and copy one from Windows to Linux. You need to create a new venv on your linux machine and install the dependencies there. This is normally done by having a requirements file that lists the dependencies for your project.

Comment: virtualenv does not behave like containerization. You need to check docker for the requirement like that,

Comment: You can `pip freeze` or `pip list` on your env on windows and then once you have made a requirements file out of it you need to activate venv in server and then you can `pip install -e your_requirements_file`.